# How to create article tables, categories and tags?

Tags: mysql, sql

I do not know how correctly integrate all these tables in 2nf SQL. I have  some tables. They look like this:

**posts**:
id, title

**categories**:
id, name

**tags**:
id, name

I would like to have one table **post-category-tag**, with fields:
(id, post_id, category_id, tag_id). Not sure if this is correct, since the article may have a ***large number of tags***. Show me please how to create this table correctly.

Comment: `post-category-tag, with fields: (id, post_id, category_id, tag_id)` looks like 3nf. What stops you applying this?

Comment: @Simonare Can you show me how some fields look like?

Comment: Actually, if a post can belong to more than one category, then I would expect there to be a table of post_categories, otherwise I would expect category_id to be a column in posts. Then I would expect there to be another table: post_tags, with no mention of categories in it. Note that there are no 'articles' here.

Comment: @Strawberry Is it right? post_category (id, post_id, category_id), post_tags(id, post_id, tag_id).

Comment: It depends on your requirements, but looks plausible to me. And, as mentioned, the surrogate key may not be necessary if the remaining columns serve to uniquely identify each row (a natural composite key).